# SVG File Shows XML Code Instead Of Image

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svg

I have been searching the web for the past few days to solve my problem it all ends up the same. The SVG image file shows XML code instead of image i have checked the content type and its correct **Content-Type: image/svg+xml** 
machine is running on Debian 8.10 x64

Comment: How are you trying to display the image?

Comment: Its like this which works fine in xampp
background: url(images/site-logo.svg) no-repeat;

Comment: Does your SVG image have correct namespaces?

Comment: The problem could be a text encoding issue or a BOM at the start of the file. It would really help if you could provide a link to this file.

Comment: Does it display in the browser if you navigate to the file directly?

Comment: How does it display the XML? Does it actually set the background to the raw XML text? Or are you looking at it in the developer tools? What does it look like in the actual page on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you should be using `background-image`, like so:

```
background-image: url(images/site-logo.svg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: That is just a path wont make any difference

Comment: The difference is using `background-image` and not `background` as in your comment.